# Allocating Resources to a network of cities using recursion in Java

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph-theory

Given a network of cities, I'm trying to allocate resources to at most numCities cities such that every city has supplies or is neighbors with someone who does in the event of a natural disaster.

Given a file, each city is turned into a String Key for a map, while the adjacent cities are stored as a set for the value mapped to each key. numCities is the max number of cities we can allocate resources to, and supplyLocations is a set that will contain the cities we've allocated resources to.

I've been trying to solve this problem with recursion using a couple different base cases, but they either return true regardless of the amount of cities given (ex. should return false if 1 is given for numCities as there is no way 1 city is neighbors with everybody) or returns false regardless of the number provided for numCities.

So far I've tried to put the cities not covered in a seperate set and once this is is 0 (i.e all cities have been covered) we return true. I've also tried hard checking if all the cities have been covered by looping through each to check if them or their neighbor is in supplyLocations.

If these base cases aren't covered, the plan is so add the city and its neighbors into a new set, and make recursive calls for each city to see if allocating to the city or its neighbors solves the problem.

Here is the code for the first interpretation, where we check if all the cities have been covered by keeping a set of uncovered cities. This interpretation always returns false regardless of the number given for numCities.

Here is one interpretation I've tried:

Helper Method:

```
public static boolean
allocate(HashSet<String>to_visit,HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>roadNetwork, int numCities,HashSet<String>supplyLocations) {

         if(to_visit.size()== 0) { 
         return true; 
     }
     
     if(numCities == 0) { 
         return false; 
     }
      
     else { 
     for(String city: roadNetwork.keySet()) {
     
     Set<String>cities_and_neighbors = new HashSet<String>();
     cities_and_neighbors.add(city); 
     if(roadNetwork.get(city)!= null) {
     cities_and_neighbors.addAll(roadNetwork.get(city)); 
     }
     for(String adjacent_city: cities_and_neighbors) { 
     supplyLocations.add(adjacent_city);
     
     
     HashSet<String>added_city = new HashSet<String>();
     
     added_city.add(adjacent_city); 
     if(roadNetwork.get(adjacent_city)!= null) {
     added_city.addAll(roadNetwork.get(adjacent_city)); 
     to_visit.removeAll(added_city);
     }
     
     if(allocate(to_visit, roadNetwork, numCities-1, supplyLocations)==true){
         return true; 
     }
     
     to_visit.addAll(added_city);
     supplyLocations.remove(adjacent_city); 
     }
     }
     }
     return false; 
     }
```

Here is the main method:

```
public static boolean allocateResources(HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>roadNetwork, int numCities, HashSet<String>supplyLocations) {
      
     HashSet<String>to_visit = new HashSet<String>(); 
     for(String city : roadNetwork.keySet()){ 
     to_visit.add(city); 
     }
     
     boolean can_allocate = allocate(to_visit, roadNetwork, numCities,supplyLocations); 
     return can_allocate; 
     }
```

Here is a sample of the code for the second approach, which hard checks if all the cities are covered by checking for cities or their neighbors in supplyLocations.

```
public static boolean allocateResources(Map<String, HashSet<String>> roadNetwork,int numCities,Set<String> supplyLocations) {
if(all_covered(roadNetwork, supplyLocations)==true && supplyLocations.size()<= numCities){
        return true;
    }
    
    if(numCities == 0){
        return true;
    }
    for(String city: roadNetwork.keySet()){
        HashSet<String>to_search = new HashSet<String>();
        to_search.add(city);
        if(roadNetwork.get(city)!= null){
            to_search.addAll(roadNetwork.get(city));
        }
        
        supplyLocations.add(city);
        if(allocateResources(roadNetwork, numCities-1, supplyLocations)==true){
            return true;
        }
        else{
        supplyLocations.remove(city);
        return false;
        }
    }
     return false;
    }
    
    
    
    public static boolean all_covered(Map<String, HashSet<String>> roadNetwork,Set<String>  supplyLocations){
        for(String cities :roadNetwork.keySet()){
            if(is_covered(cities, roadNetwork, supplyLocations) == false){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean is_covered(String city, Map<String, HashSet<String>>  roadNetwork,Set<String> supplyLocations){
            HashSet<String> to_check = new HashSet<String>();
            to_check.add(city);
            if(roadNetwork.get(city)!= null){
                to_check.addAll(roadNetwork.get(city));
            }
            for(String allocate : to_check){
                if(supplyLocations.contains(allocate)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
```

[Graph representation of the problem, with allocated cities highlighted in gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppk3n.png)

I'm wondering what the issues are with these algorithms and how to fix either one of them to get the correct results.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In graph theory, a dominating set for a graph G is a subset D of its vertices, such that any vertex of G is either in D, or has a neighbor in D.  What you're looking for is a minimum dominating set. Finding one is NP-complete in general, though if your input graphs have guaranteed properties that you haven't mentioned, it's possible there's a polynomial-time solution.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a comment, finding the best solution is NP-complete. There are lots of heuristics to get solutions that aren't the minimum. Here are a few.

- Everything: include all vertices
- BFS: Run BFS starting from any vertex. Include vertices in your set IFF their predecessor wasn't in the set.
- Greedy: Repeatedly pick the vertex that is adjacent to the most uncovered vertices. Mark the selected vertex and all its neighbors as covered.
- Greedy with leaf elimination. At the beginning and each time you add a vertex to your set, check if the graph induced by uncovered vertices has one or more leafs. If it does, pick the (possibly covered) neighbor of that leaf whose inclusion in the set will cover the most currently uncovered vertices. If there are no leafs, use Greedy until/unless there are. Repeat until all vertices are covered.

Greedy with Leaf Elimination on sample graph:

```
   A-B
   | |
   C |
   |\|
 D-E-F
   | |
   | G
   | |
   | H
   | |
   | I--J
   |/   |
   K----L
   |    |
   M----N
```

- D is the only leaf, we pick its neighbor E, covering {CDEFK}
- Leafs on G \ {CDEFK} are: A, B, G, M. We pick A's neighbor B, covering {AB}
- Leafs on G \ {ABCDEFK} are: G, M. We pick G's neighbor H, covering {GHI}
- Leafs on G \ {ABCDEFGHIK} are J, M. We pick J's neighbor L, covering {JLN}.
- M is the only uncovered vertex & only leaf. Pick it or either of its covered neighbors.

Comment: Greedy with leaf elimination gets a size-5 cover for your sample graph.